# Is Google Chrome Vurnerable to Zero Day Java Exploit like IE?

Tags: java, security, internet-explorer, google-chrome, exploit

I've seen IE 6 to 10 can be easaily exploited using the Zero Day Java Exploit (CVE-2013-0422)
And If the IE have been exploited.. We can access the hardisk file even cookies or password.. 
That's very dangerous

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dteBt.jpg)

And Google Chrome must be have the Java extention..

The question is
Is Google Chrome can be potential to the Java 0 Day Exploit.???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If the browser has Java enabled (not Javascript) then it is just as vulnerable as anything else running a vulnerable version of Java. This applies for Firefox, Safari, etc.

The only way to protect yourself is to disable the Java plugin/extension and wait for a patch.

Comment: Oh thanks. So you mean the java runtime no the javascript in the browser right. So It doesn't matter if I enable the javascript .. Coz almost All website using javascript.. Better disable my Java first

Comment: @supersam654 Oracle already released 7u11 that's supposed to correct the problem,

Comment: @fvu Yes and I'm glad they did. However, this applies to any Java exploit (be it zero-day or old).

Comment: Hey So you mean There's a previous 0 day java exploit :O

Comment: There have been tons of security problems! A quick [link](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/10/java-exploit-uptick) I found off of the Wikipedia page explains more. Most incremental updates (6.21 to 6.22 for example) usually contain at least a dozen patches. A good amount of them are usually security related.

Comment: Hoho Sorry, I'm not a security guy.Hehe
 But thanks for the information , u're a good guy ;)